# Decrypting an http responce

Tags: encoding

I made a GET request, the response headers are as follows:

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 10566
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2019 03:45:08 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

i saved the response to file, the file looks like this:

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0400 edbd 0760 1c49
9625 262f 6dca 7b7f 4af5 4ad7 e074 a108
8060 1324 d890 4010 ecc1 88cd e692 ec1d
6947 2329 ab2a 81ca 6556 655d 6616 40cc
ed9d bcf7 de7b efbd f7de 7bef bdf7 ba3b
9d4e 27f7 dfff 3f5c 6664 016c f6ce 4ada
//continues...
```

how to decode it ?

Comment: it is deflate/gzip encoded

Answer (score 0):

The response is compressed with *gzip/deflate* as indicated by the reponse header *Content-Encoding*:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

and as indicated by the first few bytes `1f 8b 08` (assuming that your question shows a hex dump of the response).

Most HTTP client libraries can easily deal with *gzip/deflate* encoding as it is a commonly used compression algorithm to speed up HTTP requests.

If your programming language or environment (unfortunately, you don't mention it), does not support *gzip/deflate*, then you can change your HTTP request. Unless the HTTP server is not working properly, your request currently includes the HTTP header *Accept-Encoding* indicating that your code can accept *gzip/deflate* encoding (which is not the case). So remove this header and the server should stop sending compressed data.